# PHP/JQUERY: 1 Query, N JSON Strings, Loop For Multiselect

Tags: php, jquery, json

Good morning all.  I have a page that does a jquery .post back to a PHP page, where a query is executed against a MySQL db and results are returned in JSON format.  There may be multiple JSON strings returned, depending on query output.  One "field" of the JSON output (appparenthcacyrsYear) is supposed to be used to select all returned values in my multiselect, but I can't get it to work.

Let me show some JSON output and what I've tried so far (shortened for SO purposes)...

Multiselect (PHP):

```
<select name="appParentHCACYrs[]" id="ParentHCACYrs" multiple="multiple" size="3">
    <?php
        $getHCACyrs = "select * from tblAppLookup where applookupCategoy = 'HCACyrs' order by applookupSortID;";
         $getHCACyrsresults = $mysqli->query($getHCACyrs);
         while ( $row = $getHCACyrsresults->fetch_object() ) {
             $id = $row->applookupItemID;
             $name = $row->applookupItemDesc;
             print "<option value=\"$id\">$name</option>\n";
         }
    ?>
</select>
```

Multiselect (HTML):

```
<select name="appParentHCACYrs[]" id="ParentHCACYrs" multiple="multiple" size="3">
    <option value="1">Year 1</option>
    <option value="2">Year 2</option>
    <option value="3">Year 3</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT: preceding jquery code, per Patirck's comment:**

```
function ProcessForm(qnum, answer) {
    $("#ContEnrollSelect").html("");
    $("#ContEnrollSelect").dialog("close");
    if (qnum == 1) {
        $.post("/chairs-dev/jqf/addapp_processajax.php", {PID: answer}, function (data) {
...
```

**addapp_processajax.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['QNUM'])) {
    $qnum = $_POST['QNUM'];

    if ($qnum == 1) {
        $getretquery = "SELECT a.parentID, concat(a.parentFName, ' ', a.parentLName) as ParentName, a.parentDOB, a.parentPriPhone from tblParents a";
    } elseif ($qnum == 2) {
        $getretquery = "SELECT a.parentID, concat(a.parentFName, ' ', a.parentLName) as ParentName, b.childID, concat(b.childFName, ' ', b.childLName) as ChildName, a.parentDOB, b.childDOB, a.parentPriPhone from tblParents a, tblChildren b where a.parentID = b.childParentID";
    } elseif ($qnum == 3) {
        $getretquery = "SELECT a.childID, concat(a.childFName, ' ', a.childLName) as ChildName, a.childDOB from tblChildren a";
    }
    $getretqueryresults = $mysqli->query($getretquery);
    while ($row1 = $getretqueryresults->fetch_object()) {
        $rows1[] = $row1;
    }

    $ret1 = json_encode($rows1);
    print json_encode($rows1);
}
```

**END EDIT**

JSON Output Example:

```
[{"appID":"2","appParentFName":"Anita","appParentLName":"Smith","appParentGender":"1","appParentDOB":"1976-04-21","appParentAddr1":"123 Main St","appParentAddr2":"","appParentCity":"Anytown","appParentZip":"12345","appParentPriPhone":"813-555-1212","appParentPriPhoneType":"2","appParentAltPhone":"","appParentAltPhoneType":"0","appParentTextable":"1","appParentEmail":"asmith@mymail.com","appParentPriLang":"34","appparentaltlangsLangID":"130","appParentHispYN":"1","appParentHispNationality":"18","appParentRace":"2","appParentHLEC":"7","appParentLastGradeComp":"12","appParentPriSecEducStatus":"1","appParentCollegeEnrolled":"0","appParentHigherEducTrainingStatus":"0","appParentRelToChild":"1","appParentLivesWith":"2","appParentMaritalStatus":"1","appParentSpouseName":"Bob","appParentNumChildrenEnrolled":"2","appparenthcacyrsYear":"1","appparenthcaclangsLang":"3","appParentOccupation":"1","appParentEmploymentStatus":"2"},
 {"appID":"2","appParentFName":"Anita","appParentLName":"Smith","appParentGender":"1","appParentDOB":"1976-04-21","appParentAddr1":"123 Main St","appParentAddr2":"","appParentCity":"Anytown","appParentZip":"12345","appParentPriPhone":"813-555-1212","appParentPriPhoneType":"2","appParentAltPhone":"","appParentAltPhoneType":"0","appParentTextable":"1","appParentEmail":"asmith@mymail.com","appParentPriLang":"34","appparentaltlangsLangID":"130","appParentHispYN":"1","appParentHispNationality":"18","appParentRace":"2","appParentHLEC":"7","appParentLastGradeComp":"12","appParentPriSecEducStatus":"1","appParentCollegeEnrolled":"0","appParentHigherEducTrainingStatus":"0","appParentRelToChild":"1","appParentLivesWith":"2","appParentMaritalStatus":"1","appParentSpouseName":"Bob","appParentNumChildrenEnrolled":"2","appparenthcacyrsYear":"3","appparenthcaclangsLang":"3","appParentOccupation":"1","appParentEmploymentStatus":"2"}]
```

Code Fail #1:

```
var oPHCACYrs = new Array();
for (i = 0; i <= obj3.length; i++) {
    if (!(typeof obj3[i].appparenthcacyrsYear === 'undefined')) {
        oPHCACYrs.push(obj3[i].appparenthcacyrsYear);
    }
}
    ...
$('#ParentHCACYrs').val(vals);
```

Code Fail #2:

```
var oPHCACYrs = new Array();
for (b = 0; b <= obj3.length; b++) {
    if (!(typeof obj3[b].appparenthcacyrsYear === 'undefined')) {
        oPHCACYrs[oPHCACYrs.length] = obj3[b].appparenthcacyrsYear;
    }
}
...
for (e = 0; e <= oPHCACYrs.length; e++) {
    $("#ParentHCACYrs option[value='" + oPHCACYrs[e] + "']").attr("selected", 1);
    $("#ParentHCACYrs").multiselect("refresh");
}
```

Could one of you kind folks out there guide me towards the proper answer?

Thank you!!

Comment: `i <= obj3.length;` Where is `obj3`? Your question make is sounds like the jquery `.post` is an integral part of this problem, but you don't show the code for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$.each` for the loop on your collection. Check **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t10npatv/)**

```
<select name="appParentHCACYrs[]" id="ParentHCACYrs" multiple="multiple" size="3">
    <option value="1">Year 1</option>
    <option value="2">Year 2</option>
    <option value="3">Year 3</option>
</select>
```

and jQuery

```
    var jsonArray = [{"appID": "2", "appParentFName": "Anita", "appParentLName": "Smith", "appParentGender": "1", "appParentDOB": "1976-04-21", "appParentAddr1": "123 Main St", "appParentAddr2": "", "appParentCity": "Anytown", "appParentZip": "12345", "appParentPriPhone": "813-555-1212", "appParentPriPhoneType": "2", "appParentAltPhone": "", "appParentAltPhoneType": "0", "appParentTextable": "1", "appParentEmail": "asmith@mymail.com", "appParentPriLang": "34", "appparentaltlangsLangID": "130", "appParentHispYN": "1", "appParentHispNationality": "18", "appParentRace": "2", "appParentHLEC": "7", "appParentLastGradeComp": "12", "appParentPriSecEducStatus": "1", "appParentCollegeEnrolled": "0", "appParentHigherEducTrainingStatus": "0", "appParentRelToChild": "1", "appParentLivesWith": "2", "appParentMaritalStatus": "1", "appParentSpouseName": "Bob", "appParentNumChildrenEnrolled": "2", "appparenthcacyrsYear": "1", "appparenthcaclangsLang": "3", "appParentOccupation": "1", "appParentEmploymentStatus": "2"},
        {"appID": "2", "appParentFName": "Anita", "appParentLName": "Smith", "appParentGender": "1", "appParentDOB": "1976-04-21", "appParentAddr1": "123 Main St", "appParentAddr2": "", "appParentCity": "Anytown", "appParentZip": "12345", "appParentPriPhone": "813-555-1212", "appParentPriPhoneType": "2", "appParentAltPhone": "", "appParentAltPhoneType": "0", "appParentTextable": "1", "appParentEmail": "asmith@mymail.com", "appParentPriLang": "34", "appparentaltlangsLangID": "130", "appParentHispYN": "1", "appParentHispNationality": "18", "appParentRace": "2", "appParentHLEC": "7", "appParentLastGradeComp": "12", "appParentPriSecEducStatus": "1", "appParentCollegeEnrolled": "0", "appParentHigherEducTrainingStatus": "0", "appParentRelToChild": "1", "appParentLivesWith": "2", "appParentMaritalStatus": "1", "appParentSpouseName": "Bob", "appParentNumChildrenEnrolled": "2", "appparenthcacyrsYear": "3", "appparenthcaclangsLang": "3", "appParentOccupation": "1", "appParentEmploymentStatus": "2"}];
    $.each(jsonArray, function(idx, obj) {
        $("#ParentHCACYrs option[value='" + obj.appparenthcacyrsYear + "']").attr("selected", 1);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't go exactly as above, BUT the reminder for "$.each" got me rolling in the right direction, which is what I needed!  :)